# OAuth Possible for Chatter Communities?

Tags: rest-api, oauth, community

Can customer community or partner community users use OAuth to authenticate and then interact with Salesforce data through the REST API?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog. You basically just need to ensure that your URL for authorization has a custom hostname.

http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html